# Convert hexadecimal string to QByteArray

Tags: c++, string, qt, qbytearray

I need to convert a `QString` which is
 already in hexadecimal format to a `QByteArray`. For example:

```
QString a = "AF5603B4"
```

Should be stored in `QByteArray` as:

```
QByteArray ba[4] = { 0xAF, 0x56, 0x03, 0xB4 }
```

How do I do this in Qt 5.9? I have tried using many methods but all of these convert the string characters to their ASCII values and then give that hexadecimal value.

I found `Convert.toByte` method to use in C# ; is there an equivalent in Qt I can use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `ByteArray::fromHex` function like this:

```
QString MyHexString ="AF5603B4";
QByteArray cmd = QByteArray::fromHex(MyHexString.toUtf8());
```

**Output**:

[image: Screenshot]

And to convert QByteArray to Hex string:

```
QByteArray cmd;
QString NewHexString = cmd.toHex();
```